# Integer multiplied by float and then divided by same float - a clean way to force value back to original integer

Tags: floating-point, floating-accuracy, floating-point-precision

Alright so we have the classic 1 * 1/3 * 3 = 0.9999999. I understand why this is the case.

In my use case, I am trying to result in an integer.  I am happy to take the floor of my value, except when infinite precision math dictates that we should have resulted in an integer to begin with (see: the above use case).

Is there a commonly used way to achieve this?

Examples:

double myFloat = 1.0/2.0;

1 * myFloat * 2 = 2   RESULT: 2

myFloat = 1.0/2.0;

2.5 * myFloat * 2 = 2.5 RESULT: 2

myFloat = 1.0 / 3.0;

1 * myFloat *3 = .9999 RESULT: 1

myFloat = 1.0 / 3.0;

.9 * myFloat *3 = .9   RESULT: 0

One way I thought of was to always tack on some delta to my result before flooring it.  I want to achieve my result in a clean, commonly accepted way though.

EDIT: Changed made for clarity based on feedback.

Comment: Why floor, rather than round to nearest integer? Rounding error is just as likely to produce a smaller-than-exact result as a larger-than-exact result.

Comment: Nearest integer is dangerous for me here.  If the value is 2.5, I for sure do not want my result to be 3.  However, if the result is 2.9999999999, I do want my result to be 3.

Comment: In that case, do a round to nearest and then compare the result to the unrounded value. If it is close enough, keep the rounded. If not, don't.

Comment: If you know the exact mathematical result would be an integer, then the proper way to convert an approximate floating-point result to the ideal result is to round it to the nearest integer, provided that the accumulated rounding errors are not so great that they reach 1/2. However, your dismissal of rounding 2.5 is puzzling. If your result is 2.5 because errors are so big that 2.5 is produced although the correct result is an integer, then your errors are too large to fix. If your result is 2.5 because some exact results are not integers, then you have to explain what the results could be.

Comment: My last example highlights a valid scenario for me.  .9 is not produced because of error - it is actually a valid result, but the end should of that scenario SHOULD BE 0, not 1.  It is only the cases where errors become an issue (they should always be very very small), I want to round to the nearest int in those cases.  The rounding to an integer and adjusting for numeric error should be considered independent.

Comment: Are you saying your ideal result is the exact mathematical value of floor(f(*x*)), for some function f, but floating-point arithmetic computes some value *y* that approximates f(*x*), and you want code that, given *y*, produces floor(f(*x*))? E.g., 2.9999…9 becomes 3 because the exact mathematical value of f(*x*) would have been 3, and floor(3) is 3, while 2.5 becomes 2 because the exact mathematical value of f(*x*) would have been 2.5, and floor(2.5) is 2?…

Comment: If so, then you should specify how much error can be in *y* and how close f(*x*) can be to an integer. If the former exceeds the latter, then the problem is generally impossible; the floating-point arithmetic has lost the information required to calculate the answer. If not, then you could choose some *e* between the two values and calculate floor(*y* + *e*).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Round f(x) to nearest integer, round(f(x))

Compare f(x) and round(f(x)). If they are close enough for the difference to be due to rounding, use round(f(x)) as result. If not, use floor(x).

If the inputs are all of similar magnitude, it may be sufficient to use abs(f(x)-round(f(x)) < epsilon for some fixed number epsilon. If not, use abs((f(x)-round(f(x))/f(x)) < epsilon for non-zero f(x).